# How to confirm payment on stripe for cards which has 3DS Auth

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to handle the customer flow who go thorough the checkout session by entering the 3D credit card and verify the 3DS authentication flow.

In my implementation I check for the redirect URL in the `payment_intent.requires_action` and redirect the customer to the URL to verify the auth.

```
payment_confirmation_link = payment_intent_object?.next_action?.use_stripe_sdk?.stripe_js
    payment_confirmation_email = payment_intent_object?.receipt_email
    if(payment_confirmation_link && payment_confirmation_email){
      const payment_confirmation_user = await User.findOne({email: payment_confirmation_email})
      console.log(payment_confirmation_user);
      merge_info = {
        "first_name" : payment_confirmation_user.name,
        "auth_link" : payment_confirmation_link
      }
```

But for some cards, next_action has a redirect URL but for 3DS cards we don't have the URL - Can someone help how we can authenticate such a user

````
      "type": "use_stripe_sdk",
      "use_stripe_sdk": {
        "directory_server_encryption": {
          "algorithm": "RSA",
          "certificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nBNY-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
          "directory_server_id": "A0XXX4",
          "key_id": "3c5ed8002388",
          "root_certificate_authorities": [
            "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIX+9DBw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
          ]
        },```
````